# How to see who is logged on on a computer on a network

Tags: windows, cmd, command-prompt

By using either the machine name or IP address is there a command I can run that returns who is logged in?

I’ve tried using:
`wmic /node:ip_here ComputerSystem Get UserName`
But this returns a invalid global switch error.

Are there any other commands that would work or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: **1.** Omit double quotes (both are `U+201D Right Double Quotation Mark`). **2.** Typo in alias: should be Comp**u**terSystem.

Comment: For instance `wmic /node:192.168.1.5 ComputerSystem Get UserName` works as well as slightly modified  `wmic -node : "192.168.1.5" ComputerSystem Get UserName`